# Is it possible to trigger htmx function by clicking on a div?

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

My current code is:

```html
<form id="search-form" hx-post="/search-api" hx-target="#search-result"></form>
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="material-icons search-button md-8 md-light" role="button" type="submit" form="search-form">search</div>
    <div class="search-bar-wrapper">
         <textarea name="search" type="text" class="search-bar" id="search-bar" form="search-form" placeholder="search" oninput="autoResize(this)"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

I can't submit the form when I click the div, do I have to add some onclick="htmx.trigger(...)" like that? I can't figure out how the `htmx.trigger` function works though.

I didn't figure it out and I just changed the "div" button into an actual button and restyled the button.

Some people say I can just submit the form with JavaScript, but it wouldn't trigger the htmx-post function at all! It would also refresh the page, so that's not it.

Comment: what event is? i found it on [here](https://htmx.org/api/#trigger)

Comment: there is no such thing as `<div type="submit">`

Comment: so its not possible?

Comment: Why do you need to? You can style a button however you want.

Comment: is it possible to use htmx with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event listener on the "button" and in the callback function call `submit()` on the form element.

```js
const searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');

searchButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.forms.searchForm.submit();
});
```

```css
.search-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .3em;
  border: thin solid gray;
  border-radius: .3em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form id="search-form" name="searchForm" hx-post="/search-api" hx-target="#search-result"></form>
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <div id="search-button" class="material-icons search-button md-8 md-light">search</div>
  <div class="search-bar-wrapper">
    <textarea name="search" type="text" class="search-bar" id="search-bar" form="search-form" placeholder="search" oninput="autoResize(this)"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

But why not just a standard form with a button and a input element for a search string like below?

```html
<form name="searchForm" hx-post="/search-api" hx-target="#search-result">
  <button type="submit">search</button>
  <input name="search" class="search-bar" placeholder="search">
</form>
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used textarea because i want to resize my input box so that it doesn't scroll and do anything annoying like that. I build this website with only mobile support in mind so scrolling in textbox while having a webpage thats also scrolling is very annoying and in my opinion very ugly lol.
Because im making the webpage with htmx, submitting via a javascript wouldnt work at all because it wouldnt trigger the htmx function, and it would also cause the website to refresh. In the end I just restyle the button lmao so yea i accidentally overcomplicated things sorry aboutdat